# Laravel problems with creating a new required validation

Tags: laravel

I am creating a new required validation based on the required_if which works fine. But I need to use this new required validation with the nullable validation in which my new required validation doesn't work. Here is my code which I use in the controller:

```
'number' => 'nullable|required_when_has_restriction:role,restriction_must_have_number|digits:11',
```

And this is the new validator:

```
class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('required_when_has_restriction', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $other = Arr::get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0]);

            $role = Role::where('name', $other)->first();
            if($role->permissions()->where('name', $parameters[1])->exists()){
                return $validator->validateRequired($attribute, $value);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I want that this validator still works when the field is null, because I need the nullable validation for the digits. Could someone explain how to solve this?

Comment: show us what have you done,,your controller code probably

Comment: Update the question with the validations you have, the result of that code and what you want the code to do.

Comment: I added the code and hopefully some better explanation for what I want to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I had to change extend to extendImplicit to have it required when there is a nullable condition

Answer (score 1):

use [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Validating When Present

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the `sometimes` rule to your rule list:

```
'number' => 'sometimes|required_when_has_restriction:role,restriction_must_have_number|digits:11'
```

Try adding `nullable` to attributes.

```
Validator::extend('required_when_has_restriction', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $other = Arr::get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0]);

        $role = Role::where('name', $other)->first();
        if($role->permissions()->where('name', $parameters[1])->exists()){
            return $validator->validateRequired($attribute, $value);
        }
        $attribute[]='nullable';
        return true;
    });
```

Or make a `custom validator`, follow [this](https://gist.github.com/byrnedo/5d07ac221d93d4af149086dda3a0dd97) link or [this](https://laravel-news.com/custom-validation-rule-objects) link.

Comment: I tried it, but when the input is empty digits is still required. The new validation works fine then

Comment: could you please show your full custom validation class and how you call it?

Comment: I have made a seperate serviceprovider for my custom validations so besides the code above there it not more

Comment: is there anything related to rules in your custom class?? show us that.

Comment: But when I add to the $implicitRules in \Illuminate\Validation\Validator RequiredWhenHasRestriction the problem is solved. Do you maybe know how to do it in my code above instead of editing this class?

Comment: then you could extend that class and override that property.  Could you please show us the full custom validator class??

Comment: Added the class but as you can see it is just a custom serviceprovider class with the validation